# Firefox top margin 0 not working

Tags: css, firefox, margin

Why margin:0 working corectly under Chrome and IE but not under Firefox? I mean that top margin under firefox isn't 0.

Website http://www.olnius.pl/

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Which rule? Which element?

Comment: Please see: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Also see: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.olnius.pl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 Any reason you don't use a doctype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<ul>` with class `.categories` has 16 px of margin on it, simply add:

```
margin: 0;
```

And you'll get rid of the margin on all sides ..

This is because some elements have margin/padding that the browser sets by default .. an easy way to reset all of the default styling is to use a CSS reset .. the most popular is Eric Meyers' reset which can be found [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Also by not using a doctype you will trigger IE to go into quirks mode so add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document.